# English words for '闺蜜'

Tags: word-request

闺蜜 in Chinese means two girls have very good relationship, and much closer than normal good friends but they are not lesbians.

闺: boudoir

蜜: connotes *honey;*

闺蜜 could be short for 闺中密友, which literally means the intimate friend in a woman’s bedroom or private sitting room.

The best I can get are  terms like **besties, intimate relationship**. Besties seems like best friends, which can be used for both men and women. Well, 闺蜜 is women only. **Intimate relationship** seems to connote a romantic relationship like lesbians.

Any other
suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could illustrate your question with a sentence, using "besties" for example.

Comment: @JamesK the sentence could be very simple. *she's my bestie. * anyways, I think I have gotten enough of it. Thanks to all.

Comment: @dan: The point isn't to find the shortest correct sentence, but to pick one that _describes_ the usage you're after. E.g. compare (a) "Tom and John were born from the same egg. They are twins." to (b) "Tom is a twin". (a) is an illlustrative sentence. (b) is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be getting hung up on it having to be specifically female. Some of these terms might not be explictly female (indeed the chinese term isn't explitly female either) but would generally be applied to women.

> Bestie (sounds like school-girl slang, or young women)
>
> Best friend (could be male or female, but "she is my best friend" works. This is by far the simplest solution)
>
> Bosom buddy/friend (this used to be applied to both men and women, but now seems to be almost entirely female)
>
> Girlfriend, (when used by a woman of another woman can just mean "friend who is a girl, especially in US English)
>
> Cater cousin (old-fashioned and rather rare)

Sometimes it is better to describe rather than translate:

> She was more than a good friend; we did everything together.

If I had to go for one compound, I'd use "bosom friend".

Comment: What about *ladybro*?

Comment: what about it?  Its a fairly ugly word, recently coined.  I didn't suggest womance for the same reason.

Comment: About the "ladybro", Chinese-English dictionary always gives a lot of words, haha. I also find, confidante

Answer (score 9):

The closest I can think of is to say they get along

> like sisters.

This would suggest that the relationship is closer than friends, but decidedly not sexual. Although obviously sisters don't always get along, I would only use this for women who *do* get along and feel comfortable around each other.

Answer (score 6):

The term [**soulmate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soulmate) is one that can be used for both men and women and yet its meaning ranges from *close sexual relationship* to *best friends*. Here's how Wikipedia defines it:

> A soulmate is a person with whom one has a feeling of deep or natural affinity. This may involve similarity, love, romance, comfort, intimacy, sexuality, sexual activity, spirituality, compatibility and trust.

Example:

> Susan and Betty were real **soulmates**. They shared all their intimate secrets with each other.

---

Another good word would be [**confidante**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confidante), but this one only applies to a single woman and not a pair of women. Although *they were each other's confidantes* could make sense in certain situations, this is not how it's usually used. Depending on the context, you might find it useful too. Here's its definition:

> Someone's confidante is a woman who they are able to discuss their private problems with.

Example:

> You are her closest friend and **confidante**.

Comment: I have never in my life heard the word *soulmate* used in a non-romantic sense (I'm in the UK). Wikipedia [seems to agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soulmate#Current_usage) that it usually means romantic. Certainly that would be the assumption if one were told that two people were soulmates, and it would require further clarification to get across that it is a friendship.

Comment: I found *confidante* is a very good word for this sense. Is *confidante* a female version of *confidant*? Are they pronounced the same with/without *e*? Is the person who has a confidante necessarily a woman? Or both men and women could have a confidante? Thanks!

Comment: @dan Yes, in English they're pronounced the same way: https://forvo.com/word/confidante/#en It's a word that originally comes from French where it's common for nouns that represent types of people and professions to have one version for men and another version for women. So, yes, *confidante* is the female version of *confidante*. I'd say a woman as well as a man can have a confidante. See additional examples at the bottom of the page I linked you to in my answer. It's not a super daily word, though.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin is it only for single women? The definition from my dictionary doesn't suggest that.

Comment: @dan What do you mean by *is it only for a single woman*? A confidante is a woman with whom one has a very intimate relationship. That's what it basically means.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin you said in you answer "...but this one only applies to a single woman".

Comment: @dan Yes, a confidante is only one woman. You wouldn't say *confidantes* to mean a pair of woman that have an intimate relationship. Again, see the examples on the web page I have the link to in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin I misunderstood *a single woman* as *a woman who is single, unmarried*.:)

Comment: @MichaelRybkin maybe, this brought another question: do a single woman usually mean one woman or a unmarried woman?

Comment: @dan I'd say without additional context that makes it clear what exactly it is that you're talking about, *a single woman* probably means a woman who is not married.

Comment: -1 for "soulmate" which is what you call someone you want to spend the rest of your life with. +1 for "confidente", only someone really close, like a best friend or close relative can be a confidente, a person with whom you share your deepest fears and darkest secrets.  Total score =0